# Linux program trying to load two different revision of a shared library at the same time

Tags: g++, shared

my problem sound a bit strange

I have build a library , named libJsonCpp.so,  which I used in some of progam and now I have simply increased the revision number of that library, from 2.12 to the 2.13.

```
[enzo@P0101222 Test]$ ls -la /prd/b_BCM/bin/libJsonCpp.so*
lrwxrwxrwx    1 enzo     aesys          18 Mar 16 16:52 /prd/b_BCM/bin/libJsonCpp.so -> libJsonCpp.so.2.13
lrwxrwxrwx    1 enzo     aesys          18 Mar 16 14:26 /prd/b_BCM/bin/libJsonCpp.so.2 -> libJsonCpp.so.2.13
lrwxrwxrwx    1 enzo     aesys          22 Mar 16 14:26 /prd/b_BCM/bin/libJsonCpp.so.2.13 -> libJsonCpp.so.2.13.001
-rwxr-xr-x    1 enzo     aesys      286939 Mar 16 14:26 /prd/b_BCM/bin/libJsonCpp.so.2.13.001
```

The strange thing is that the programs that is using this library try to load it twice, the new reivison and the old ones

When I check  the program to see what library it required I have an output like this:

```
  [enzo@P0101222 MySampleProgram]$ ldd MySampleProgram
        libJsonCpp.so.2.13 => /prd/b_BCM/bin/libJsonCpp.so.2.13 (0x4002a000)
        libxerces-c-3.0.so => /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c-3.0.so (0x40061000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0x40438000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x4044c000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x40461000)
        ...... 
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 => /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x40000000)
        libJsonCpp.so.2.12 => not found
```

As you can see the program look for the new library ( correct )

```
libJsonCpp.so.2.13 => /prd/b_BCM/bin/libJsonCpp.so.2.13
```

but also for the old ones, whic of course was been removed

```
    libJsonCpp.so.2.12 => not found
```

I have checked in all the system to found where there should still be a reference to the old revision but I found nothing.
I also rebuild the program e delete the cache files, but the problem is still here.

So I'm asking if someone had some suggestion about what to check to find out this strange problem.

Regards, Enzo

added 17.3.2015
During the link of the program I have the following error:
it seems that the link /prd/b_BCM/bin/libJsonCpp.so point ti the old revision, but the links are all linked to the new ones ( see above )

```
g++ -Wcast-qual -Wshadow -Wcast-align -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-long-long -Wbad-function-cast -Wundef \
-Wall -pedantic -W -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -ansi -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 \
-D_BSD_SOURCE -Wcast-align -Wconversion -fno-builtin -g -O2 -O0 -g3 -Wall \
-I.. -Ibcm_plant -Ibcm_panel -Ibcm_display -Ibcm_common -I../bcm_panel -I../bcm_display -I../bcm_common \
-fno-exceptions -fno-check-new -fexceptions -rdynamic \
-o MySampleProgram gestconfigbcmmessage.o clsmsgwritestatus.o testcr01.o util_panel.o updatefirmwaredisplay.o main.o \
/prd/b_BCM/bin/libJsonCpp.so  ./bcm_plant/libbcm_plant.a ./bcm_panel/libbcm_panel.a ./bcm_display/libbcm_display.a \
./bcm_common/libbcm_common.a /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c.so -lnsl -lpthread /usr/lib/libstdc++.so \
-L/usr3/BUILD/gcc/gcc-3.4.6/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src \
-L/usr3/BUILD/gcc/gcc-3.4.6/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs -L/usr3/BUILD/gcc/gcc-3.4.6/gcc \
-L/usr/local/lib -L/prd/b_BCM/src/b_BCM_common/modules -leasyzlib -lftplib -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libJsonCpp.so.2.12, needed by /prd/b_BCM/bin/libJsonCpp.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/enzo/Autostrade/prd/b_BCM/src/MySampleProgram/MySampleProgram'
```

Comment: Either your program or one of those other libraries you depend on needs the old version. My [tldd](https://gitlab.com/miscripts/tldd) utility will show the same output as ldd but in a tree, so you can tell which file has the dependency on the old library

Comment: unluckily I'm using a very old revison of linux ( redhat 7.3 ) so I don't think I should use your utility which I usppose require a very new revisoon of compiler.

Comment: RH 7.3? **Why?!**  anyway, you can still do it by hand, just use something like `readelf -d file | grep DT_NEEDED` on your program and each of its dependencies, and each of their dependencies, until you find the one that depends on the old lib

Comment: Thank for the suggestion of readelf but this give me a strange result. Readelf list only the right library , not mention to the old one.  But the ldd commend still shiw the old dependency `[enzo@P0101222 ]$ readelf -d MySampleProgram | grep NEEDED
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libJsonCpp.so.2.13]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libxerces-c-3.0.so]
 .....
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]`

Comment: As I said, you need to use readelf on each of the libraries, and their dependencies too, not just on the main program

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the probem.

For some strange reason the new lib contain a reference to the old ones.

```
$ ldd  /prd/b_BCM/bin/libJsonCpp.so.2.13
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x4004d000)

        libJsonCpp.so.2.12 => not found

        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 => /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x80000000)
```

Luckily was enough to rebuild the new library and the wrong dependency disappeared

Thank Jonathan for you support.

Reagards, Enzo